# 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'select_db_flag' error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help as I have a problem with my current code. I'm trying to call the GoRight function, but it will give me an error: **AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'select_db_flag'**

The error are jumping on this line:

```
if select_db_flag == True:
```

Here is the code where I use to call the GoRight function from move_right.py:

```
import move_right

class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):
    def GoRight(self):
        move_right.GoRight(self)
```

Here is the code where the error are found:

```
import datetime
import time
import xbmc
import xbmcgui

prog_id = 0
select_db_flag = False
program_stop_minutes = 0
program_stop_time = 0
epg_time_1 = ''
epg_time_2 = ''
epg_time_3 = ''

def get_programming_times(self):
     if select_db_flag == True:
         select_db_flag = False



 def GoRight(self):
    program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
    programs_id = list()
    program_width = list()
    positions_X = list()
    positions_Y = list()

    for elem in program_button:
        programs_id.append(elem.getId())
        positions_X.append(elem.getX())
        positions_Y.append(elem.getY())
        program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
    programs_id = map(str, programs_id)
    posX = map(str, positions_X)
    posY = map(str, positions_Y)
    program_width = map(str, program_width)

    for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
        if int(pos_X) == 375 and int(prog_width) == 1311:
            programs_width = 969
            self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))
            program_width = self.getControl(int(prog_id)).getWidth()
            select_db_flag = True
            program_stop_minutes, program_stop_time, epg_time_1, epg_time_2, epg_time_3 = get_programming_times(self)


            if program_stop_time == epg_time_3:
                if program_stop_minutes == '00':
                    if program_width == 969:
                       program_width = 692
```

I have defined the `select_db` on the top of my code, but it did not help me when I get the error.

Do you know why I have got an error and do you know how to fix it?

Comment: was it your intention that `select_db` be a global variable, or a variable unique to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
def get_programming_times(self):
     if select_db_flag == True:
         select_db_flag = False
```

with this:

```
def get_programming_times(self):
    global select_db_flag
    if select_db_flag == True:
         select_db_flag = False
```

You should use global everytime you call a global variable, so you probably need  `global select_db_flag` in the other functions too.

Edit:
Additional problem fix from comments:

```
def get_programming_times(self):
    global select_db_flag,program_stop_minutes,program_stop_time,epg_time_1, epg_time_2,epg_time_3
    if select_db_flag == True:
        select_db_flag = False
    return program_stop_minutes,program_stop_time,epg_time_1,epg_time_2,epg_time_3
```

This will fix the error, but might cause others or return the wrong results.

If you copy code from the internet, try to understand it instead of randomly doing this with it.

Comment: Also, use `if select_db_flag:`, not `if select_db_flag == True:`

Comment: thank you very much for this, but i am getting the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` in this code `program_stop_minutes, program_stop_time, epg_time_1, epg_time_2, epg_time_3 = get_programming_times(self)` do you know why and how to fix it?

Comment: @user3788310 well, get_programming_times does not return anything, so the line makes no sense at all...

Comment: what i am trying to do is to get the return information. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @user3788310 I know what it should do. I am saying there is not enough information to do it correctly. I used a hotfix in the edit above. But this will probably not make it work and we would be here for hours. Try reading some tutorials and understanding the code